# What is the correct way to configure a spring TextEncryptor for use on Heroku

Tags: heroku, spring-security

I have a spring TextEncryptor defined like this

```
<bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors"
                                                  factory-method="text">
        <constructor-arg value="${security.encryptPassword}" />
        <constructor-arg value="${security.encryptSalt}" />
</bean>
```

Which is fed these properties

```
security.encryptPassword=47582920264f212c566d5e5a6d
security.encryptSalt=39783e315e6a207e733d6f4141
```

Which works fine on my local environment. When I deploy to Heroku I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to initialize due to invalid secret key
at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils.initCipher(CipherUtils.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.AesBytesEncryptor.encrypt(AesBytesEncryptor.java:65)
at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.HexEncodingTextEncryptor.encrypt(HexEncodingTextEncryptor.java:36)
...
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:972)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:738)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:797)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1276)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1215)
at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils.initCipher(CipherUtils.java:105)
... 53 more
```

So I tried some smaller keys but I always get the same problem. What is the correct key size to use on Heroku?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I think I've concluded Heroku just plain doesn't support 256 bit AEP which is what the stock TextEncoders in spring-security use.

Instead I've used the BasicTextEncryptor from the [Java Simplified Encryption](http://www.jasypt.org/) library as an alternative backend and implemented the TextEncryptor interface.

It's less secure but it works. It doesn't provide a salting mechanism, though I think there are provisions for that elsewhere in the library.

If anyone has any ideas how to get the stock encryptors working on heroku then that would still be preferable I think.

Answer (score 13):

My answer is a bit late but I wrote it to help anyone in need. By default, spring security uses a 256-bit key for encryption. This is not permitted by the JDK by default, which supported up to 128-bit keys only.

To solve this, you need need to download the **local_policy.jar** & **US_export_policy.jar** jars from oracle ([Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7 Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)) and replace them in jdk_path/jre/lib/security/. Make sure you restart the application server for the changes to take effect.

On a separate note, I wouldn't place the secret key in a properties file. Instead I recommend you put it in a key store. If you need help with that let me know.

Comment: Yes that is the correct solution for a local install. The point is on a remote managed platform like heroku we don't have control over the JDK.

Comment: I just amazing - why these files are not bundled with java.

Comment: @msangel I'd say that its a US Crypto export restriction.  I'm surprised we (those who are non-US citizens) have such free access to them).

Comment: Are you able to outline the advantages of a keystore? Would that require also storing the password to the keystore somewhere in plain text?

Comment: Hi John, the whole concept is not having the password in plain text format in a properties / XML config file. We got this marked as a "Low Priority" issue by one security auditor.

Comment: This link is for Java 8 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Comment: This also worked for me after placing the files under the JRE path of "maven --version".

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following.  Though this seems to have stopped working on the latest builds of Java 8.

```
    Field field = Class.forName("javax.crypto.JceSecurity").getDeclaredField("isRestricted");
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(field.get(null))) {
        if (Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())) {
            Field modifiers = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
            modifiers.setAccessible(true);
            modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        }
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.setBoolean(null, false); // isRestricted = false;
        field.setAccessible(false);
    }
    textEncryptor = Encryptors.text(key, salt);
```